# Menu does not display in Firefox 13 on Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, xubuntu

I had a problem after update firefox to version 13.
When I start the firefox, it works. But for a while I can't click on firefox menu anymore. The right click menu doesn't work either.

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04 64 bits:

> Linux minh-desktop 3.2.0-26-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 17:49:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Everytime I get this problem, I have to restart the firefox.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [safe mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) or [making a new profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles)?

Comment: I tried safe mode but I got that problem after 30 minutes.
Is there any way to get some useful log?
Thank you.

Comment: I upgraded to firefox 14.0.1 but still have this issue.

Comment: I suggest you also post your query [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/index.php) and [here](http://support.mozilla.org/).

Comment: I encountered this problem upon upgrading from 13.0.1 to 14.0.1.  I downgraded to 13.0.1 and it works fine again.  Here is a bug that was filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1026747

Comment: Thanks blujay, I added a comment to that bug.
I also post the issue to [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/932643) as the vasa1 suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

By helps from pschrammel on support.mozilla.org, I removed the ~/.pulse-cookie directory then it solves the problem.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/932643